# Would it be troublesome to bring Swift files into a OC project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've already had a Objective-C version big project. Now I want to develop the future features in Swift. I know it's easy to use Swift in Objective-C.
But what makes me worried is **whether it would make any trouble like some build errors.**
Especially， I'am using CocoaPods to import a doze of Objective-C version frameworks. 
Would it make errors by adding `use_frameworks!`?

I've already gotten a problem that I should change `<>` to `""` to import frameworks installed by CocoaPods.
I'm not sure whether it would cause any other problems or not. That's why I'm asking this question.
So, I will be really appreciate if someone could tell me is it safe or not to use Swift in Objective-C project.

Comment: Maybe not, but it might makes size much bigger(?) since it have to include swift runtime

Comment: Also, please make sure you use `@import xyz` instead of `#import "xyz.h"` to avoid this kind of hassle in future.

Comment: It also depends upon your swift version.

Comment: @User511 Which one is better? Swift3 or Swift4?

Comment: @atulkhatri OK. Thank you.

Comment: It should work on swift 3 because swift 4 has syntax changes.

Comment: @User511 Every swift version has syntax changes. You can never get away with that. Future XCode versions will deprecate the older versions so it's always better to use the latest swift version. I think you should go with Swift 4.

Comment: For swift 4 you have to make sure that the libraries you are using in your project should have updated swift 4 versions because all the libraries are not updated in swift 4.

Comment: Swift4 seems better, I develop a Obj-C framework using in Swift project, and get lots trouble.
The static lib will not support the use_frameworks!,  take care of it

Comment: @menq Thanks. Ok. Thank you.